# UIScrollView doesn't work when add a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I'm doing some tests with Xcode 5 (just started) and I have a problem that I can not find solution. I have a storyboard with a ViewController that contains a UIScrollView, which add different ViewControllers as the follow:

```
self.firstView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstView"];
[self.generalScrollView addSubview:self.firstView.view];
```

The problem is that the scroll doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add your `self.firstView` anywhere? Do you present it somehow? (BTW it should be `self.firstViewController`, not `view`).

And if you do, did you set up the correct `contentSize` on the scroll view for it to scroll? It should either be bigger than the frame in one dimension, or you could use `self.generalScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES` option for the scroll view.

Here's some reference code for how to set the appropriate contentSize:

```
self.generalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.generalScrollView.frame.size.width, 800);
```

Comment: Ok, if only add self.firstView gives me an alert: "Incompatible pointer types sending..." but fortunately this code works:

    self.generalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.firstView.frame.size.width, self.firstView.frame.size.height);
Thanks!

Comment: @eledgaar you have to be very careful how you name variables in obj-c. Glad to be of help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the content size?

```
[self.generalScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.firstView.frame.size.width, self.firstView.frame.size.height)];
```

/*
also, shouldn't the addSubview read: self.firstView 
instead of 
self.firstView.view >> Edit no, it shouldn't - it's a view controller, so my bad - sorry for not reading correctly
*/

Comment: No it shouldn't because `self.firstView` is a `UIViewController`.